# Create an array of values which appear in both given arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I need to create an array with values which appear in both of the given arrays.

I was thinking about looping through each of the arrays and comparing values, if they match increase a 'counter' variable which will be the length of the new array, loop through the new array and assign the values to array elements.

I need to figure out a solution with a loop, code below is what I've got so far

```
class New {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr1[] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10};
        int arr2[] = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8};

        int counter = 0;
        int combined[] = new int[counter];

        for (int s = 0; s < arr1.length; s++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < arr2.length; x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
                    if (arr1[s] == arr2[x]) {
                        counter++;
                        combined[i] = arr1[s];
                    }

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(combined[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: `I need to figure out a solution with a loop` You mean without a loop?

Comment: What do you need the counter for?

Comment: I can't declare an array in Java without the size of the array, that's why I created counter variable, to count how many matching values there are which will be the size of the array

The problem with this code is that it doesn't print anything in the console, the last loop is supposed to print out the variables of the array

Comment: @Julia I see now. Yes well, you are creating your array with size 0. `int combined[] = new int[counter];` This array will not resize itself when you increment the counter. And I think `combined[i] = arr1[s];` will throw an Exception anyway. There are several other problems with the code honestly.

Comment: I liked the fact that this post got many answers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you initialise your `combined` array to 0 so it will not contain anything and the second problem is that you have one `for` loop to many, the one over the `combined` array.

Instead you need to create a temporary array that will be large enough to cover all possible duplicates and then copy from the temporary array to an array of the right size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr1[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10 };
    int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 5, 6, 8 };

    int min = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length); //We can never have more duplicates than the number of elements in the smallest array
    int counter = 0;
    int combined[] = new int[min];

    for (int s = 0; s < arr1.length; s++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < arr2.length; x++) {
            if (arr1[s] == arr2[x]) {
                combined[counter] = arr1[s];
                counter++;
                break; //We have found a duplicate, exit inner for loop and check next digit in outer loop
            }
        }
    }
    int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(combined, counter); //This makes a copy of the array but only with the number of elements that are used
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `Arrays.copy` you can do the copying yourself, just replace that line with

```
int[] result = new int[counter]
for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
    result[j] = combined[j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] intersection(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    Set<Integer> elements = IntStream.of(arr1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return IntStream.of(arr2).filter(elements::contains).toArray();
}
```

Or using only `int[]`:

```
// create temporary array to not modify input data
int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length);
Arrays.sort(tmp);

for(int v : arr2)
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(tmp, v) >= 0)
        System.out.print(v + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
int[] intersection = IntStream.of(arr1)
            .filter(v1 -> IntStream.of(arr2).anyMatch(v2 -> v2 == v1))
            .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't learned .filter(), .findAny() and other methods in class yet, unfortunately my teacher won't accept this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick  :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr1[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10 };
    int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 8 };

    int combined[] = new int[arr1.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            if (arr1[x] == arr2[i]) {
                combined[x] = arr1[x];
            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(combined[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

1. You don't need 3 loops to find duplicates between two arrays.
2. Here the outer loop iterates over the bigger array (arr1) and the inner
   loop iterates over the smaller array(arr1).
3. `combined` is defined to have the same size of the larger array (to avoid any `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`)
4. After the nested loop is completed, `combined` will hold only the
   duplicate entries along with some zeroes as it was initialized using the *size* of `arr1`. (As an exercise you can alter the loop to filter out the non-zero elements indicating the duplicates only!)

Comment: It gives incorrect result for `[7,2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10]` and `[ 1, 5, 4, 8,2 ]`. Also, wouldn't these leave gaps in between in the combined array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Missed to include the last element of the inner loop. Its addressed now.  Regarding the `0`, that can always be removed/filtered out I've included a note as well for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve this using only arrays and iterations,
you can:

1. sort input arrays:  O(n log n)
2. iterate thru arrays: O(n)

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    // make sure input arrays are sorted
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);

    List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {

        int v1 = arr1[i];
        int v2 = arr2[j];

        if (v1 == v2) {
            common.add(v1);
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (v1 < v2) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(common);
}
```

on each iteration you move forward:

- arr1's index (i)
- or arr2's index (j)
- or both

**no ArrayList version:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);

    int found = 0;
    int[] common = new int[Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {

        int v1 = arr1[i];
        int v2 = arr2[j];

        if (v1 == v2) {
            common[found] = v1;
            found++;
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if (v1 < v2) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < found; k++) {
        System.out.println("common: " + common[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr1 = {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10};
        Integer[] arr2 = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8};
        List<Integer> integers = Stream.of(arr1)
                .filter(Arrays.asList(arr2)::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(integers);
}
```

Output will be:

```
[2, 5]
```